# how to Instantiate prefab with view as a grid in side camera view

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

i want to create a view like grid with prefabs inside camera view but i'm unable to do so. prefabs are going out of the camera view. can any one help me to resolve this? i want to place prefab as a grid and 9 * 6 grid.

```
public GameObject tilePrefab;
    Vector2 mapSize;

    void Start()
    {
        createGrid();
        Debug.Log("Screen Width : " + Screen.width);
        Debug.Log("Screen Height : " + Screen.height);
        mapSize = new Vector2(Screen.width/9,Screen.height/12);
        Debug.Log("mapSize : " + mapSize);

    }


    void createGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
            {

                Vector3 tilePosition = new Vector3(-mapSize.x+0.5f + x,-mapSize.y + 0.5f+y ,0 );

                GameObject ballclone = (GameObject)Instantiate(tilePrefab,tilePosition,Quaternion.identity);
                ballclone.transform.parent = transform;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The create grid function is way off. Think about what you are trying to do and what the offsets should be. Also, make sure your camera is orthographic and remember that screen-size != viewable area

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewportToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html)

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
         xx.position = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1f/9*x, 1f/6*y, distance));
```

`distance` is the distance between the camera and the object.